# Best practice to deploy war file on cluster?

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, war, haproxy

I have a cluster of 3 tomcat on which my application is deployed and there is haproxy for loadbalancing . I am looking out for a way to automate the rolling deployment such as

1. Setting a node to maintaince mode in haproxy.
2. Take source code from git.
3. Create a war file and deploy it to particular node.
4. Check if application is successfully running on tomcat.
5. Set state of the node as ready.
6. Repeat the steps from 1 to 5 for other nodes too.

I came across Jenkins in which I will be having one master and rest slave and would have chaining of jobs, having an ant file to create a war on each node and copying it to webapps folder of tomcat.

Is there any other way? What do big companies follow to do rolling deployment??

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using some auto deployment tool like Vagran, Chef, Puppet